# System.Runtime.Serialization::ObjectIDGenerator

Tags: .net, serialization, lookup

I just tried to use System.Runtime.Serialization::ObjectIDGenerator in my application. My application needs to communicate with another proccess. For this purpose I need to exchange object IDs between processes. The ObjectIDGenerator class seemed to be the solution... until I found that there is an lookup Object -> ID but no lookup ID -> Object.

Is there a better ready-to-use solution that allows reliable and fast lookup in *both* directions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`ObjectIDGenerator` just keeps a hash-table over the objects it has seen, and an assigned object id.

Here is a simplified version in C#:

```
public class MyObjectIdGenerator
{
    private Dictionary<int,List<int>> _hashToID = new Dictionary<int,List<int>>();
    private List<object> _objects = new List<object> { null, };
    private int _idCounter = 1;
    private int _numRemoved = 0;

    public int GetId(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        int hash = RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(obj);

        List<int> ids;
        if (!_hashToID.TryGetValue(hash, out ids))
        {
            ids = new List<int>();
            _hashToID[hash] = ids;
        }

        foreach (var i in ids)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(_objects[i], obj))
            {
                return i;
            }
        }

        // Move the counter to the next free slot.
        while (_idCounter < _objects.Count && _objects[_idCounter] != null)
        {
            _idCounter++;
        }

        int id = _idCounter++;
        ids.Add(id);

        // Extend the pool to enough slots.
        while (_objects.Count <= id) {
            _objects.Add(null);
        }
        _objects[id] = obj;

        return id;
    }

    public bool Remove(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;

        // Locate the object
        int hash = RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(obj);
        List<int> ids;
        if (!_hashToID.TryGetValue(hash, out ids)) return false;

        foreach (var i in ids)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(_objects[i], obj))
            {
                // Remove the object, and clean up.
                _objects[i] = null;
                ids.Remove(i);
                if (ids.Count == 0)
                {
                    _hashToID.Remove(hash);
                }
                _numRemoved++;
                if (_numRemoved >= 10 && _numRemoved >= _objects.Count/2) {
                    // Too many free slots. Reset the counter.
                    _idCounter = 0;
                    _numRemoved = 0;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public object GetObject(int id)
    {
        if (id < 0 || id >= _objects.Count) return null;
        // 0 => null
        return _objects[id];
    }
}
```

Here are the decompiled sources of ObjectIDGenerator: http://www.fixee.org/paste/30e61ex/

**Edit:** Added `Remove` method.

Comment: BTW, what happens if objects that are registered in MyObjectIDGenerator are no longer needed? The MyObjectIDGenerator keeps them alife by holding a reference to them, right? Does this prevent unused objects from being trash-collected that way?

Comment: That is correct. The standard `ObjectIDGenerator` also keeps the objects alive as long as it is. If you need the objects to be collectible, you could wrap each object in a `WeakReference`.

Comment: Very interesting. So I definitely need to use weak references for my two-way-lookup object-ID generator. If I understood those weak references correctly I need to check "IsAlive" before using the reference. right? However this still means the object-ID-generator caches the weak reference, even if it is dead. This also means the internal tables of the object ID generator will grow infinitely even if the majority of the contained references are dead already, right?

Comment: Is there a way to get informed if a cached object is trash-collected so I can remove the corresponding weak-reference completely from the internal tables?

Comment: No there is not. You could add some heuristics when an object is added to the cache, such that every 100th time, it goes trough the list and removes all dead references.